# How to use FindFirstFile

Tags: c++, pointers, stdstring, lpcwstr

I keep getting compile errors with the line at the bottom

```
hFind = FindFirstFile(fileFilter.c_str()), &FindFileData);
```

The compiler keeps throwing `error C2664 back at me,  : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'`

How do I create a LPCWSTR to a std::string to pass to into FindFirstFile?

Zhe section of code is for reference.

The actual code follows below.

```
using namespace std;

void GetFileListing(string directory, string fileFilter, bool recursively = true)    
{    
    if (recursively)
        GetFileListing(directory, fileFilter, false);

    directory += "\\";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind ;
    string filter = directory + (recursively ? "*" : fileFilter);
    string Full_Name;
    string Part_Name;

// the line causing the compile error

    hFind = FindFirstFile(fileFilter.c_str()), &FindFileData);
```

Comment: use wstring instead of string

Answer (score 3):

The WinAPI data types are lovely short abbreviations. `LPCWSTR` is short for:

```
Long
Pointer to the start of
Const
Wide
STRing
```

As such it is a pointer (long pointers are history) to the first character of a const wide string (`const wchar_t*`), meaning you need to use `std::wstring::c_str()` instead of `std::string::c_str()`.

Side note: just be sure to `#define UNICODE` everywhere you use the WinAPI, otherwise you'll get other errors about conversion to `LPCSTR`. Alternatively, explicitly use the `W` versions of the WinAPI functions where they exist.